# ASP.NET authenticate against windows with IIS set to anonymous

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, asp.net-4.5

Is it possible to have an ASP.NET site which authenticates against AD and runs in an IIS site set to Anonymous?

Here is the backstory. I wrote an ASP.NET site that works fine, but it is getting deployed to a server that doesn't have Windows Authentication setup and I guess there is some concern of turning it on since there are other sites on this server. My site has a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to check if the logged in user matches up with a list of users or groups like this:

```
[AuthorizeUsers(Groups = @"Admins", Users = @"domain\user1,domain\user2")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Now my thinking is that it's fine if IIS is set to anonymous because once the user hits my application, this `AuthorizeAttribute` will kick in, they get prompted for credentials, those get passed in, and they get verified. This doesn't happen though. Even after getting prompted, their username is not getting picked up by my application. Here is the rest of the relevant code.

```
public class AuthorizeUsers : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Groups { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //This check ends up always being false
        //I've tried commenting it out, but httpContext.User.Identity.Name always comes in empty
        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Groups))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get the AD groups
                    var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList<string>();

                    // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
                    var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                    var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,
                                                         IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                                         httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

                    foreach (var group in groups)
                    {
                        if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                //string msg = e.Message;
                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Users))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get the AD groups
                    var users = Users.Split(',').ToList<string>();
                    string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

                    foreach (var name in users)
                    {
                        if (name.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //string msg = e.Message;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is web.config

```
<authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

I've tried a couple of different things, but I always get a 401 Unauthorized for user Anonymous. I guess I am just confused about what is happening when the browser prompts for user credentials and I enter my domain\username.

EDIT
It looks like there isn't a workaround for this. When you set IIS to Anonymous, the browser doesn't send the user credentials to the server so there is no way to check who the user is. I will have to turn on Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "username is not getting picked up by my application" what exactly do you mean ? Does the user keep getting prompted for credentials ? Also could you please clarify the substatus code for 401 you are receiving.

Comment: I mean in this line "httpContext.User.Identity.Name" the result is always blank. In my mind this would hold the username that was just entered in the login prompt. Why else would that log in prompt even come up? Well that was my thinking, but I think that when you set IIS to Anonymous, then it doesn't send the the user info to the server so there really is nothing I can do. It looks like I will need to turn on windows authentication after all.